# Custom float for algorithm does not position correctly

Tags: floats, environments, algorithms, newfloat

I'm trying to write a custom environment to style algorithms, and have LaTeX position them as floats.

For now I have this:

```
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=algf,placement={!tbp},name=Algo]{myfloat}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}

\newcounter{cnt:alg}
\newenvironment{myalgo}[3][!tbp]{
    %\noindent
    %\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    %\vbox\bgroup
    \begin{myfloat}[#1]
        \begin{center}
            \hrulefill\\\vspace{3pt}
            \refstepcounter{cnt:alg}\label{#2}
            \textbf{Algorithm \ref{#2}:} #3\\
            \vspace{-2pt}\hrulefill
        \end{center}
}{
        \begin{center}
            \vspace{-5pt}\hrulefill
        \end{center}
    \end{myfloat}
    %\egroup
    %\end{minipage}
}
```

The various commented lines represent the different approaches I've tried. Out of them, the `vbox` is the one that works best, but does not behave like a `float`. Using `myfloat` seem to work at a first glance, but if the algorithm is long enough it starts behaving erratically (at least from my point of view). Most of the time the algorithms end up completely alone in a page, even if text could be easily fit alongside them. They also seem to mostly ignore the `htbp` options (or more likely, they are not ignored but are not doing what I'm expecting them to do).

Am I doing something wrong with the `newfloat` environment?

Full MWE follows. The algorithm ends up alone in the second page. If it is shortened, it gets correctly fit in the text.

```
\documentclass[final]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=algf,placement={!tbp},name=Algo]{myfloat}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}

\newcounter{cnt:alg}
\newenvironment{myalgo}[3][!tbp]{
    %\noindent
    %\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    %\vbox\bgroup
    \begin{myfloat}[#1]
        \begin{center}
            \hrulefill\\\vspace{3pt}
            \refstepcounter{cnt:alg}\label{#2}
            \textbf{Algorithm \ref{#2}:} #3\\
            \vspace{-2pt}\hrulefill
        \end{center}
}{
        \begin{center}
            \vspace{-5pt}\hrulefill
        \end{center}
    \end{myfloat}
    %\egroup
    %\end{minipage}
}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{myalgo}{alg}{Algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require{Inputs}
    \Ensure{Outputs}
    \While While
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \EndWhile EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{myalgo}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can't have a float in a box so the commented vbox and minipage could not work. Having a default position of `!tbp` is a little odd as `!` means "ignore the default constraints.  If you use `\begin{myalgo}[ht]{alg}{Algorithm}` it comes at the top of page 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The float does not fit on page 1, but is bigger than half `\textheight` which is `\floatpagefraction` so it makes a float page with just this float before starting page (3).

You can use `[ht]` (or just `[t]`) so a float page is not considered for this float, or you could use

```
\usepackage{fewerfloatpages}
```

which modifies the placement algorithm so it will try a top float rather than a float page in this case.

[image]

Avoid `!` in default placements.

```
\documentclass[final]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{fewerfloatpages}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=algf,placement={htbp},name=Algo]{myfloat}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}

\newcounter{cnt:alg}
\newenvironment{myalgo}[3][htbp]{
    %\noindent
    %\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    %\vbox\bgroup
    \begin{myfloat}[#1]
        \begin{center}
            \hrulefill\\\vspace{3pt}
            \refstepcounter{cnt:alg}\label{#2}
            \textbf{Algorithm \ref{#2}:} #3\\
            \vspace{-2pt}\hrulefill
        \end{center}
}{
        \begin{center}
            \vspace{-5pt}\hrulefill
        \end{center}
    \end{myfloat}
    %\egroup
    %\end{minipage}
}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]


\begin{myalgo}{alg}{Algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require{Inputs}
    \Ensure{Outputs}
    \While While
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \State State
    \EndWhile EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{myalgo}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify some of your float parameters, such as `\topfraction`, `\bottomfraction` and `floatpagefraction`.

```latex
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.7}
```

Add this line after `\documentclass[final]{article}`, and you will find it floating.

---

Besides, you should use `\arabic{cnt:alg}` instead of `\ref{#2}`. In this way, only one compilation is needed to display the serial number correctly.

Comment: you need to be careful though, if you _only_ change that setting, a float that is .69\textheight can not be placed, less than `\floatpagefraction` but adding `\floatsep`  bigger than `\topfraction`